# Selection sort comparisons and swaps on an already sorted list

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

One of the questions in my sample final paper is: How many comparisons and swaps do selection sort algorithm make if the input, of size n, is already sorted? Show your work how you derive the numbers. Assume swap is done only when it is necessary. https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1Fhw.jpg

My logic for `{1, 3, 4, 5, 7}` is that

1 is compared to 3 4 5 7, so n-1 comparisons and 0 swaps

3 is compared to 4 5 7, so n-2 comparisons and 0 swaps

4 compared to 5 7, so n-3 comparisons and 0 swaps

5 is compared to 7, so n-4 comparisons and 0 swaps.

So the number of comparisons would `n-1 + n-2 + n-3 + n-4`. And the number of swaps would be zero.

Is my logic correct? And if so, how do I answer this question for any n length elements?

Comment: Please read [Open letter to students with homework problems[(https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/48428) and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Your logic is correct for selection sort. For the general formula, `(n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) ... + (n-n+1)` works out to `(n*(n-1))/2`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort#Complexity for details.

Answer (score 0):

No your logic is wrong. You don't understand how it works.These are two loops for insertion sort.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j > 0 && less(a[j], a[j-1]); j--) {
                exch(a, j, j-1);
            }
            assert isSorted(a, 0, i);
```

1 is not compare to 3 4 5 but 3 is compared to 1 and since it is greater then inner for loop breaks, then 4 is compare to 3 since 4 > 3 then again inner loops breaks.

Try to plug in values and see that inner loop will break and no exchange will take place. So in total you have O(n-1) compares which is O(n).

If you reverse the input array then it will have worst time complexity, namely O(n^2) compares and swaps.

Comment: I am so sorry. I meant selection sort in the title, not insertion sort. I fixed it. Hope you can answer it.

Comment: for selectionSort it's correct, that always does O(n^2) compares

Comment: We haven't done this O stuff (I believe its called Big O notation?) yet. Can you come up with the number of comparisons without using it or is it not possible for a given n?

Comment: Yes it's Big-O notation. What you wrote in your answer is correcct. First it compare `n-1` numbers then `n-2` then `n-3` and so on. Here i it finds minimum element and replace it with first element then second minimum with second element etc...

Comment: @hyden55Printf if you compute this series then you get like this: n +(n-1)+(n-2)+ .... + 1 and big-O just takes the highest term which is n(n-1) = n^2 - n and with Big-O you throw again lower order terms O(n^2 - n) = O(n^2). It's just an upper bound.

Comment: That series sums to `(n^2 - n)/2`. Still O(n^2).

Comment: @JimMischel yeah forgot to write 2 btw i never use Big-O , I prefer ~ notation and yes 2 should be there.